# search access multi-valued filed

Tags: ms-access

I'm having trouble getting Access to search on a multi-valued filed for a report. The multi-valued field is Group_List, and when trying to search a value in the multi-valued field and I keep getting the error that says cannot search in a where or having a clause. In the report, if I search for a value in the field I would only like those values to show up in the report.

```
Private Sub Command284_Click()
    Dim reportsearch As String
    Dim reportText As String
    Dim strReport As String

    If IsNull(Me.txtReport.Value) Then
        strReport = "'SELECT * FROM NCECBVI'"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "NCECBVI-Report", acPreview, , strReport
        txtReport.Value = ""
    Else
        reportText = Me.txtReport.Value
        reportsearch = "[Last Name] LIKE ""*" & reportText & "*"" OR [First Name] LIKE ""*" & reportText & "*"" OR Group_List LIKE "" * " & reportText & " * """
        DoCmd.OpenReport "NCECBVI-Report", acPreview, , reportsearch
        txtReport.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I used multi-valued fields for a couple of minutes once... I think you need to put `Group_List.Value`  [Guide to multivalued fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guide-to-multivalued-fields-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31#bm7)

Answer (score 0):

Although I highly recommend to not use this kind of "dynamic query", there is a way to handle that kind of criteria for mutivalued fields.

Supposed that your `Group_List` is filled from a `Groups` table that as a `GroupID` and a `GroupName` column, you need to join your `Groups` table to the `NCECBVI` table (Connecting `GroupID` and `Group_List.Value`) and apply the criteria to the `GroupName` field. To show every record of the `NCECBVI` table only once, use `DISTINCTROW`. The assembled query would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW NCECBVI.* 
FROM NCECBVI
  INNER JOIN Groups ON Groups.GroupID = NCECBVI.Group_List.Value
WHERE Groups.GroupName LIKE "*SomeText*"
```

To deal with queries on multi-valued fields, I recommend [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a).